# Responsive table headers not showing

Tags: html, css, responsive, css-tables, vuetify.js

I am looking for a solution for a responsive HTML table and the closest CSS solution I have found is:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }

  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
  }

  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
  }

  table td::before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
  }
}
```

However, the issue with this is I need to have a static `data-label` for each of my `td` so that the column header will, which is not very scalable. Does anyone know a way I can write the CSS that will automatically show the column header without me having to specify `data-label`? Here is my jsfiddle with the current solution where I manually specify `data-label`:

https://jsfiddle.net/tgpfhn8m/1051/

Comment: As far as I can see the data-label you're using needs to be static as it will always have these values. If you want to change the titles dynamically then add a dynamic content into the data-label

Answer (score 0):

#### you should try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>

    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```